# How and when we will be able to use Catalyst for our own projects to vote?

Tags: catalyst, voting

I know that voting project Catalyst is still under development and it will be most probably in this state till end of 2025 but can we expect to vote on our own projects inside Cardano ecosystem and also outside Cardano (using only the infrastructure)?

If this is possible how this will gona happen and when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can already vote using the Catalyst mobile app if you have ADA in a wallet you control.

That said, it's still in a kind of beta phase that depends on the Ideascale platform.

In the end, there will probably be a voting section inside the Daedalus and Yoroi wallets and we will no longer need Ideascale for the voting process.

It is unknown yet how long it will take to build this and finish Voltaire era.